# Why is my numeric validation method not catching certain strings as being invalid numbers?

Tags: java

I currently have a validation method which returns a boolean based upon whether a given String is a valid Double, Float, Integer, Long, or Short. Whilst this seems to catch cases such as "asdf" as being an invalid string, it seems to fail when there is an invalid numeric string which starts with a series of numbers e.g.: "33asd". The method is shown below:

```
    public static boolean isNumeric(String str, Class<? extends Number> cl) {
    try {
        if (cl.equals(Byte.class)) {
            Byte.parseByte(str);
        } else if (cl.equals(Double.class)) {
            if (NumberUtils.convertStringToDouble(str, "###,###") == null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (cl.equals(Float.class)) {
            Float.parseFloat(str);
        } else if (cl.equals(Integer.class)) {
            Integer.parseInt(str);
        } else if (cl.equals(Long.class)) {
            Long.parseLong(str);
        } else if (cl.equals(Short.class)) {
            Short.parseShort(str);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The NumberUtils.convertStringToDouble method used above is:

```
    /**
 * @param number
 *            - The String to convert.
 * @param format
 *            - The format of the string representation of the double (e.g:
 *            "###,###.00")
 * @return The String as a java.lang.Double if its valid; otherwise null.
 */
public static Double convertStringToDouble(String number, String format) {

    try {
        NumberFormat num = new DecimalFormat(format);
        return num.parse(number).doubleValue();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does NumberUtils look like?

Comment: Show us a call for which it fails.

Comment: What is the `cl` argument when it fails with `"33asd"`?

Comment: What do you pass in as parameter cl when you test "asdf"? It seems to me if you pass in cl as anything other than the classes in your if-else ladder ( String for example ), this method will always return true.

Comment: the cl argument for when it fails is Double.class

Comment: Did you use a debugger?

Comment: @EdgeCase the code for the relevant NumberUtils method is now included

Comment: Would this method not be better if it took an Object as its only parameter, looked to see what Object type it was, and then undertook your if-else ladder? what;s to stop me pass a "123.456" as parameter one and Byte.class as parameter 2?

Comment: @DaveHowes The first argument is of type `String`---always. The second argument does not specify the type of the first argument, but the requested target type into which it must parse. It is not redundant.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - you're right - I'd skipped the writing at the top and gone straight to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented for [`DecimalFormat.parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29),

> parsing does not necessarily use all characters up to the end of the string

So, by the time the parser reaches the alphabet character, it already has something which parses into a legal number, and simply stops there.